# In Android Studio, after importing a tensorflow lite model, how can the generated sample code be used?

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Via android studio, I added a new .tflite ([specifically the one found here](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/deeplabv3/1/metadata/2)). It generated the following sample code :

```
try {
    LiteModelDeeplabv31Metadata2 model = LiteModelDeeplabv31Metadata2.newInstance(context);

    // Creates inputs for reference.
    TensorImage image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);

    // Runs model inference and gets result.
    LiteModelDeeplabv31Metadata2.Outputs outputs = model.process(image);
    List<Category> segmentationMasks = outputs.getSegmentationMasksAsCategoryList();

    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
    model.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Handle the exception
}
```

`LiteModelDeeplabv31Metadata2` can't be found. Is that a class I need to create or can it be imported from somewhere?

Comment: Did you manage to overcome the problem? Do you still need help?

Comment: it seemed to be ok after exiting and reopening android studio...im not sure how to refresh otherwise

Answer (score 0):

`LiteModelDeeplabv31Metadata2` should be auto-generated and there should be no issue for you to reference.

Make sure you have following section in your build.gradle

```
buildFeatures {
  mlModelBinding true
}
```

Could you check the steps in https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#4.1-tensor-flow-lite-models?

Also here is a youtube video about how to use it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_XOVkjXQbU